# C++ Splitting classes into multiple files. Explicit type int assumed when I specified a type

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

I've been having an issue when splitting classes across multiple files. I get 2 errors, explicit type is missing ("int" assumed) and missing type specifier int assumed. I have looked everywhere and found nothing

This is my class header file
    //Class.h

```
#pragma once
class Class
{
public:
   Class();
    ~Class();

    int function(); //i specified a type here
};
```

I'm trying to use function and I did specify a type which is int

This is my class cpp file

```
//class.cpp

#include "Class.h"

Class::Class()
{
}


Class::~Class()
{
}

Class::function() //This is the error line. Class::function has a red 
                  //underline under it
{
    int x;
    return x;
};
```

Comment: You still need to specify the *return type* when defining the member functions.

Comment: `Class::function()` -> `int Class::function()`

Comment: do you... even... try...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .cpp file use this:

```
int Class::function()
```

since in the header file you declared function to have a return type of int.  You need to do the same in the .cpp file.

Comment: function is **not** "of type int"

Comment: In his Class.h file he has this line 
"int function(); //i specified a type here"
Which indicates its supposed to return a value of type int.  So in his implementation file he has to specify it as int.

Comment: there is no such thing as function of type int. That is just nonsense. The type of the function is: "function taking no argument and returning int". You may say function returning int, but never "function of type int"

Comment: I think we're discussing semantics.

From this link http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function.

The first line about function declaration "A function declaration introduces the function name and its type. A function definition associates the function name/type with the function body. "

Notice it mentions declaring the functions type.  But yes we all know that means it's return type.  I don't think you and I are wrong in our statements.

Comment: @CDVAProgrammer Sorry, but you really are wrong. When it says "function type", it means exactly what bolov wrote, or `int ()` in C++ syntax, rather than just its return type.

Comment: @CDVAProgrammer allow me to disagree with you. The function type is, as I've said "function receiving no arguments and returning an int". By your definition `int f1()`  `int f2(float a, float b)` and `int x` would all be of the same type. And no, not everybody knows this. I (used to) teach and a lot of students make this confusion.

Comment: you do are stubborn. You edit doesn't make it better, because "function of type int" is not another way of saying "a function who returns int". It is just incorrect. Tell me, would you say `int f2(float a, float b)` to be of type int? Would you say `auto f3() -> int` to be of type int? Would you say `auto f4(float a, float b) -> int` to be of type int? would you say `auto f5() { return 24; }` to be of type int?

Comment: Understood.  I may not explain things the best way.  But I do agree with your points.  And have edited it for clarity.  Wasn't trying to be stubborn or combative.  I just legitimately thought in simple discussions that saying function has type int would be easily associated with saying that it has a return type of int.  Once again I do concede to your points and have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @CDVAProgrammer thank you. I am not a "more catholic than pope guy" and I do agree and use myself abuses of language and oversimplifications when they are commonly used. But in this case the type of a function is a clear well defined concept and it is in direct contradiction with just saying it's return type which causes confusion. And I've seen first hand this exact confusion in students. Again thank you for understanding.